# KeyError: 'Default'. This is the kind of error I get when I try to run my application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am new to python and the flask framework, this may seem trivial but i am at an impasse. When I try to run my flask application it gives me the error **keyError: 'default'**.

Here's my code separated on three different *.py* modules

***manage.py***

```py
import os

from flask_script import Manager, Shell
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from app.models import User, Role
from app import create_app, db

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')

manager = Manager(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)


@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return dict(db=db, User=User, Role=Role)

manager.add_command('shell', Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

***config.py***

```
import os 

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET_KEY' or 'hard to guess string'
    SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN = True
    FLASKY_MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Flasky]'
    FLASKY_MAIL_SENDER = 'Flasky Admin <flasky@example.com>'
    FLASKY_ADMIN = os.environ.get('FLASKY_ADMIN')
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 587
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True
    MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')
    MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

    @staticmethod
    def init_app(app):
        pass


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DEV_DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data-dev.sqlite')



class ProductionConfig(Config):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')

config = {
    'development': DevelopmentConfig,
    'production': ProductionConfig,

    'default': DevelopmentConfig
}
```

***app/__init__.py***

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from config import config


bootstrap = Bootstrap()
mail = Mail()
moment = Moment()
db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    app.config[config_name].init_app(app)

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

And here's the Traceback information am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 513, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 380, in main
    return AppGroup.main(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 423, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 152, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 176, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 237, in load_app
    rv = locate_app(self.app_import_path)
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 90, in locate_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/flasky.py", line 8, in <module>
    app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
  File "/home/charlson/Vscode/flasky/app/__init__.py", line 19, in create_app
    app.config[config_name].init_app(app)
KeyError: 'default'
```

What is expected is a simple web page along the port http://localhost:5000, in my local machine

Any assistance will be proudly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Remove code `app.config[config_name].init_app(app)` after loading config i.e `app.config.from_object(config[config_name])`

You successfully loaded conf data to your app and then you can access the config values that you specified in config class. Its just like accessing normal dict, so it didn't have any attribute like default its causing error.

try running application after removing code `app.config[config_name].init_app(app)` it will work fine.

ref this [page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/) for more info

Comment: Thanks it works fine... I thought it best to instantiate the config first!!.